# Using the installed Materialize SASS gem

Tags: ruby, node.js, sass, materialize

I'm trying to set up a Materialize SASS project, but being new to SASS I'm having trouble wrapping my head around how to actually use it.

I have Ruby and Nodejs installed (I'm on Windows).

As per https://github.com/mkhairi/materialize-sass, I've run:

```
$ gem install materialize-sass
```

It has now installed successfully, but where is it actually *located*? How do I *use* this in a project?

With the framework Foundation, I would run "foundation new" in a given folder, but Materialize doesn't seem to have a similar command. And I can't find any documentation for this.

Answer (score 1):

Asked a while ago - but in case someone else lands here:

The Materialize Sass gem - like all gems, is installed in your gem directory (the terminal command 'gem env' provides that path if you don't know where it is).  If you walk down the directory structure, you'll see the stylesheets and the javascripts directories - you just need to call these into your application's stylesheet and application.js file.  For instructions on how to do that - check out the developers' [github repository](https://github.com/mkhairi/materialize-sass).